# Java MyBatis Freemarker Dynamic SQL

Tags: java, mybatis, freemarker, dynamic-sql

i use MyBatis (with Freemarker driver) in a spring boot application, accessing to query with the @Mapper and @Select annotations.

```
@Mapper
public interface DataRepository {

    @Lang(FreeMarkerLanguageDriver.class)
    @Select("/sqlMappers/module/findList.ftl")
    public List<DomainDto> findItemsMatchingFilter(
            @Param("entityId") Long entityId,
            @Param("commonSearch") CommonSearch commonSearch);
```

I have some particular queries that I would like to be saved in databases and run by MyBatis at runtime (the idea is to modify the queries to dynamically generate some XLSX reports).

Is it possible with MyBatis (I'd like to use it to not have to worry about sql injection and other similar aspects)?

Thanks,
Gabriele

Comment: It would be possible to execute execute arbitrary SQL string `@Select("${sqlString}")`, however, MyBatis does not check SQL injection, etc. at all.

Comment: Ok, now it's clear.

Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,
with mybatis-freemarker is not possible.

I think i will save it in a DB table with freemarker format, so i will execute them as native query.

The business requirement is to create a little engine to execute custom query on DB and export them as excel file.